# Keras model order of inputs

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer

I had 3 separate models that were basically in the structure of user-item.  I wanted to merge these and then run a a few layers post merege.  However, when it came time for the inputs, I first got an error.  I had assumed that I would need inputs in the structure of `[item1, user, item2, users, item3 users]`, which matched the inputs from my 3 initial separate models.  However, on doing so, it basically said, 'you can't repeat inputs'.  However, something feels wrong with the `[item1, item2, item3, user]` structure to me, even though it runs with decent results.  Should I simply duplicate the users to make a user1, user2, user3 that are identical?

Code below:

```
#Making the vctors for the primary categories
item1_input = Input(shape=[1])
item2_input = Input(shape=[1])
item3_input = Input(shape=[1])
user_input = Input(shape=[1])

item1_vec = Flatten()(Embedding(nb_item1s + 1, 32)(item1_input))
item1_vec = Dropout(0.5)(item1_vec)


item2_vec = Flatten()(Embedding(nb_breweries + 1, 32)(item2_input))
item2_vec = Dropout(0.5)(item2_vec)


item3_vec = Flatten()(Embedding(nb_item3s + 1, 32)(item3_input))
item3_vec = Dropout(0.5)(item3_vec)

user_vec = Flatten()(Embedding(nb_users + 1, 32)(user_input))
user_vec = Dropout(0.5)(user_vec)

# Next, we join them all together and put them
# through a pretty standard deep learning architecture
item1_input_vecs = add([item1_vec, user_vec])
item1_nn = Dropout(0.5)(Dense(128, activation='relu')(item1_input_vecs))
item1_nn = BatchNormalization()(item1_nn)
item1_nn = Dropout(0.5)(Dense(128, activation='relu')(item1_nn))
#item1_nn = BatchNormalization()(item1_nn)
#item1_nn = Dense(128, activation='relu')(item1_nn)
item1_result = Dense(9, activation='softmax')(item1_nn)

item2_input_vecs = add([item2_vec, user_vec])
item2_nn = Dropout(0.5)(Dense(128, activation='relu')(item2_input_vecs))
item2_nn = BatchNormalization()(item2_nn)
item2_nn = Dropout(0.5)(Dense(128, activation='relu')(item2_nn))
#item2_nn = BatchNormalization()(item2_nn)
#item2_nn = Dense(128, activation='relu')(item2_nn)
item2_result = Dense(9, activation='softmax')(item2_nn)

item3_input_vecs = add([item3_vec, user_vec])
item3_nn = Dropout(0.5)(Dense(128, activation='relu')(item3_input_vecs))
item3_nn = BatchNormalization()(item3_nn)
item3_nn = Dropout(0.5)(Dense(128, activation='relu')(item3_nn))
#item3_nn = BatchNormalization()(item3_nn)
#item3_nn = Dense(128, activation='relu')(item3_nn)
item3_result = Dense(9, activation='softmax')(item3_nn)

result_vecs = Concatenate()([item1_result, item2_result, item3_result])
result_vecs = Dropout(0.5)(result_vecs)

final_nn = Dense(128,activation='relu')(result_vecs)
final_nn = Dropout(0.5)(final_nn)
final_result = Dense(9, activation='softmax')(final_nn)

finalmodel = Model(inputs=[item1_input, item2_input, item3_input, user_input], outputs=final_result)
finalmodel.compile(optimizer='adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy')


finalhistory = finalmodel.fit([a_item1id, a_item2id, a_item3id, a_userid], a_y, 
                     epochs=20, 
                     validation_data=([b_item1id, b_item2id, b_item3id, b_userid], b_y), verbose=1)
```

Comment: Please include the full and real error messages in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct as it is. Your model has one input (`user_input`), then inside the model you are using this `Input()` in three different layers.

Comment: So, interestingly enough I ran it both as above [item1, item2, item3, user] and as [item1, user1, item2, user2, item3, user3] to see if it made a difference, and it does not - gives exact same answer, so you are correct that it is treating using it in all three different layers correctly.